# Не получается в одном SQL запросе: Получить имя человека. По этому имени получить COUNT его различных действий в спортивном матче

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Добрый день, в данный момент занят решением для статистики в спорте.

Строю веб-приложение, создающую таблицу с индивидуальными результатами игрока из базы данных (по game_id).

Застрял на моменте, когда получаю имя игрока, вывожу через цикл в таблицу и нужно загрузить остальные данные - сколько раз его имя встречается совместно с определенным типом действия - передача, бросок, потеря. Как сделать одинарным запросом к БД понимание есть. Как сделать это все в рамках одной таблицы, да еще и запрашивая все данные циклом по действиям с переменной "имя игрока" - нет.

Догадываюсь, что все очень просто, параллельно смотрю учебник по php.
Думаю может быть создать на каждое действие свой sql statement, но можно ли в одном сделать несколько запросов?

И могу ли я создать новый цикл с переменной "имя игрока" и уже по нему запрашивать данные по действиям? соответственно тоже поставить в цикл и сделать вывод в таблицу.
Подскажите пожалуйста, знатоки, в каком направлении рыть

По итогу хочу получить такую таблицу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже полный php код запроса в БД и вывода в таблицу.

```html
<?php

require "connection.php";

$game_id = 1760;
$player = 'KURBANOV, NIKITA';
$team = 'CSKA Moscow';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM game_results WHERE game_id = :game_id AND team = :team AND action = "Assist" ORDER BY player DESC');
$stmt->execute(array('game_id' => $game_id, 'team' => $team ));
$result = $stmt -> fetchAll();

echo '<table class="table table-condensed table-hover"><tbody>';
echo '<thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>POS</th>
                  <th>MIN</th>
                  <th>PTS</th>
                  <th>OREB</th>
                  <th>DREB</th>
                  <th>TREB</th>
                  <th>AST</th>
                  <th>STL</th>
                  <th>TOV</th>
                  <th>Fm</th>
                  <th>Fc</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>';

foreach( $result as $row ) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['player'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['action'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

и ниже пример содержимого в базе данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Привет. Вы попали на "Stack Overflow **на русском**".

Comment: @D-side, а как попасть в английскую версию дополнительно?
Похоже что я не на том языке изначально задал вопрос, да?первое мое появление на сайте не задалось:(

Comment: На доменное имя сайта обратите внимание. У "большого SO" нет `ru.`.

Comment: То, что там есть сбивающий с толку баннер регистрации в русскоязычной версии, известная проблема. Но чинить, к сожалению, не торопятся.

Comment: *Похоже что я не на том языке изначально задал вопрос, да?* Похоже, похоже... только непонятно, почему понимание проблемы есть, а вот корректировки вопроса и перевода на русский язык по-прежнему незаметно...

Comment: @Akina, был в зале. Спасибо, перевел.
Если есть идеи - подскажите пожалуйста:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно вас понял, то вот такой запрос вернет список: игрок-действие-кол-во действий

```
select player, action, count(1)
  from statistics_table
 group by player, action
```